# What is this ScalaRX code doing?

Tags: scala, rx-scala

So I'm pretty new to both Scala and RX. The guy who knew the most, and who actually wrote this code, just left, and I'm not sure what's going on. This construct is all over his code and I'm not really clear what its doing:

```
def foo(List[Long]) : Observable[Unit] =
  Observable {
    subscriber => {
      do some stuff
      subscriber.onNext()
      subscriber.onCompleted()
    }
```

I mostly get `do some stuff`, and the calls to subscriber. What I don't get is, where does `subscriber` come from? Does `subscriber => {` instantiate the subscriber? What does `Observable { subscriber => { ... } }` do/mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Observable companion object](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Observable$) documentation, you will see an `apply` method that takes a function of type `(Subscriber[T]) ⇒ Unit`. So, when you call `Observable{withSomeLambda}`, then this is the same as calling `Observable.apply{withSomeLambda}`

And, if you go all the way to the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/blob/0.x/src/main/scala/rx/lang/scala/Observable.scalahttp://) you will see that this is really returning

```
toScalaObservable(rx.Observable.create(f))
```

where `f` is the lambda that you passed in.

So, `subscriber` is just the parameter of the lambda. It is passed in by the caller of that function.

Comment: I keep forgetting about the implicit .apply(). Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

This code is creating a new `Observable` as described [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html).

Basically when a downstream component subscribes to this stream, this callback is called. In the callback we determine when we, as a data source, will call `onNext(v: T)` which is how we pass each element we are generating to them, and when we will call `onCompleted()` which is how we tell the subscriber that we are done sending data.

Once you have created an `Observable` you can start calling [Observable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Alphabetical-List-of-Observable-Operators), which will either result in another, compound `Observable`, or will result in a terminating condition which will end the process, and generally result in a final result for the flow (often a collection or aggregate value).

You don't use the `List` in your question, but normally if you wanted to make a reactive stream out of a list you would call `Observable.from()`.

PS: I think this is RxJava code.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I accepted the other answer just because it hit on the .apply() syntax I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Np, glad you're making progress.